# Creating instance variable doesn't work?

Tags: java, variables, instance

it's been a while since i've used JAVA.

I am trying to create an instance variable in order to used a method in another class.

But it gives me this error message that says "The constructor BB is undefined"

Any help?

```
public class AA implements CC { //this is the class where I am trying to create an instance variable

        public int Get() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Please implement me.");
        BB fifo = new BB(); // this is where I am declaring.
    }
}
```

And there is the signature of FIFOLock class.

```
public class BB implements DD {
       public int Get() {}
}
```

Comment: *"been a while since i've used JAVA."* It has matured enough now that we do not feel the need to SHOUT about it.  So now you can just call it 'Java'.

Comment: What constructor definitions do you have in BB and DD?

Comment: I don't see any instance variable there...

Comment: I don't know why I capitalized all the letters in it, thanks for reminding me though. any help?

Comment: In BB, I just have public BB (String name) { mt = name} mt is a type  thread by the way.

Comment: Your title is saying one thing while the description other?

Comment: @user1658855  I don't understand the question.  1) Don't abstract it so much (e.g. `BB extends DD`) put meanigful names. 2)   For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  3) Note also that 'any help?' is not a specific question and you'll get better help (and sound less pathetic) by forming an explicit & specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement `BB fifo = new BB();` should be before

`throw new IllegalStateException("Please implement me.");`

Comment: This shouldn't be right. I tried anyway, but obviously didn't work. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: No your `throw` statement will be the last statement of your method from that the control goes to the exception handling code so you may get `Unreachable code` error

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are getting that error message but the problem is likely to be that you are writing code is a place which can never be executed (after you throw an Exception)

I suggest you remove the exception or place it at the end of your method.

BTW I suggest you use `camelCase` for methods and use `UnsupportedOperationException` as `IllegalStateException` says the object is in a state which mean the method cannot be used i.e. another confusing error.

Also there is a `FIFOLock` lock builtin so I suggest you use that `new ReentrantLock(true);` is a fifo lock.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a **1-arg constructor** or any **n-arg constructor** in your class, then you should also declare a **0-arg constructor** on your own.. Because `Compiler` will not do it for you..

Compiler only adds default constructor, when there is no other constructor declared in your class..

So, if you want to use:  -`BB obj = new BB()`, declare a **public constructor** in your BB class in addition to the already existing constructor you have : -

```
public BB() {
}

public BB(String arg) {  // Whatever constructor you have declared
}
```

**OR, if you cannot change the class, create instance using the 1-arg constructor: -**

```
 public int Get() {
    BB fifo = new BB("rohit"); // this is where I am declaring.
    throw new IllegalStateException("Please implement me.");
 }
```

**NOTE**: - You should have the `throw` statement after instance creation line.. Else, the code will not `Compile`.. As that would be `UnreachableCode`

Answer (score 0):

add default constructor,do like this :

```
public class BB implements DD {
BB()
{
}

       public int Get() {}
}
```

Comment: This is a project for my class, and I am not supposed modify BB class. In BB class, I have: public BB (String name) { mt = name} mt is a type thread by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following in your `BB` class

```
   public BB() {
    }
```

I suspect that you have used a **Parametrized constructor** in your `BB` class without creating the **default constructor/No argument constructor**. If you have default constructor in your `BB` class then make it `public` so  that it can be accessed it other class too.

Comment: This is a project for my class, and I am not supposed modify BB class. In BB class, I have: public BB (String name) { mt = name} mt is a type thread by the way.

Answer (score -1):

As you said that you have `public BB (String name) { mt = name}`

**You should have mentioned the above in your code.**

Then you should initialize the Instance of class BB in class AA like this:

`BB b = new BB("Vivek");`

**ie.** with a String as an argument.

And place your `BB b = new BB("Hello");` before the **throw** statement.

Comment: What is the string as an argument supposed to be? Just any string?

Comment: I just added a random string as an argument, and now it says "Unreachable code"

Comment: Place your BB b = new BB("Hello"); `before the throw statement....`